# Are exact sequence homomorphisms unique?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, exact-sequence

Oftentimes I see examples short exact sequences written as $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ without explicitly saying what the morphisms are. Of course the definition requires ${\rm im}(g) = \ker(f)$, but a lot of times in text the functions are omitted. For example, $0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0$ is a famous example of a non-split exact sequence, yet the morphisms are implicit or an exercise for the reader.

This leads me to wonder whether, fixing $A$, $B$, and $C$, are the morphisms uniquely determined? Or do there exist groups (or another algebraic structure) $A$, $B$, $C$ such that there are multiple distinct short exact sequences of the form $0 \to A \to B \to C$ with differing morphisms?

Comment: No, they are not. You should be able to find many examples one which the modules are vector spaces for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's entirely possible to have multiple distinct short exact sequences. For a cheap example, you can take any (nontrivial) automorphism $\varphi$ of $B$. Then if we have a short exact sequence

$$
0 \to A \overset{\iota}{\to} B \overset{\pi}{\to} C \to 0
$$

we get a new short exact sequence by composing with $\varphi$:

$$
0 \to A \overset{\varphi \circ \iota}{\to} B \overset{\pi \circ \varphi^{-1}}{\to} C \to 0
$$

You might reasonably complain about this, and ask if there are any less silly examples. Here the answer is *also* yes, but we need to make explicit what we mean by "less silly".

Say that two extensions
$0 \to A \overset{\iota}{\to} B \overset{\pi}{\to} C \to 0$
and
$0 \to A \overset{\iota'}{\to} B' \overset{\pi'}{\to} C \to 0$ are *equivalent extensions* iff there is an isomorphism $\varphi : B \cong B'$ so that the following diagram commutes.

[image: The usual extension diagram defining equivalence classes in Ext groups]

Then it's possible for $B$ and $B'$ to be isomorphic as mere abelian groups, but *not* equivalent as extensions!

The quickest way to see this requires a very cool fact that you may not know: The set of extensions of $C$ by $A$ up to equivalence [forms a group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor), called $\text{Ext}^1(C,A)$. It turns out to be routine (with practice) to calculate these groups in simple cases -- this is the subject of [homological algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homological_algebra).

Then we can compute, for instance, $\text{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}/p, \mathbb{Z}/p) \cong \mathbb{Z}/p$. This tells us that there are $p = |\mathbb{Z}/p|$ many inequivalent extensions $E$ fitting into a diagram
$0 \to \mathbb{Z}/p \to E \to \mathbb{Z}/p \to 0$.

Of course, there are only two possible choices of $E$ up to isomorphism, since it must be an abelian group of order $p^2$! Either $E \cong (\mathbb{Z}/p) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/P)$ or $E \cong \mathbb{Z}/(p^2)$. In particular, when $p \neq 2$, there are more classes of inequivalent extensions than there are possible middle terms! So we must have $E$ and $E'$ which are isomorphic abstractly but *not* equivalent as extensions!

In a situation like this, writing $0 \to \mathbb{Z}/p \to \mathbb{Z}/(p^2) \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$ is ambiguous, because we don't know which extension is meant! For instance, if $p \neq 2$ then

$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}/p \overset{1 \mapsto p}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}/(p^2) \to \mathbb{Z}/p \to 0
$$

$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}/p \overset{1 \mapsto 2p}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}/(p^2) \to \mathbb{Z}/p \to 0
$$

are inequivalent extensions! Of course, in practice, almost nobody writes this down explicitly, since the extension in question is usually "clear from context" once you get used to things.

---

I hope this helps ^_^